# Why riverpod state that store List of String always reset its value?

Tags: flutter, riverpod, riverpod-annotation

I have built this riverpod state:

```
import "package:riverpod_annotation/riverpod_annotation.dart";

part "form_state.g.dart";

@riverpod
class FormState extends _$FormState {

  @override
  List<String?> build() {
    ref.listenSelf((previous, next) {
      log("previous: $previous, next: $next", name: "FORMSTATE 0");
    });

    return List.filled(10, null);
  }

  void change(int index, String value) {
    log("change: $index, value: $value", name: "FORMSTATE 1");
    state = [
      ...state.sublist(0, index),
      value,
      ...state.sublist(index + 1),
    ];
  }
}
```

---

On my Widget, I have a list of `TextField` as Below:

```
class DummyPage extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const DummyPage({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<DummyPage> createState() =>
      _DummyPageState();
}

class _DummyPageState extends ConsumerState<DummyPage> {
  final List<TextEditingController> _controllers =
      List.generate(10.length, (index) => TextEditingController());

  @override
  void initState() {
    final form = ref.read(formStateProvider);

    for (var i = 0; i < _controllers.length; i++) {
      _controllers[i].text = form[i] ?? "";
    }

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    for (var i = 0; i < _controllers.length; i++) {
      _controllers[i].dispose();
    }

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return Column(children: [
      ...List.generate(
        _controllers.length,
        (index) => TextField(
          controller: _controllers[index],
          onChanged: (val) {
            ref.read(formStateProvider.notifier).change(index, val);
          }
        )
    ])
  }
```

The current condition is every time `onChanged` is called, it always resets the value as below:

```
[FORMSTATE 0] previous: null, next: [null, null, null, null, null, null]
[FORMSTATE 1] change: 0, value: 2
[FORMSTATE 0] previous: [null, null, null, null, null, null], next: [2, null, null, null, null, null]

[FORMSTATE 0] previous: null, next: [null, null, null, null, null, null]
[FORMSTATE 1] change: 1, value: 3
[FORMSTATE 0] previous: [null, null, null, null, null, null], next: [null, 3, null, null, null, null]

[FORMSTATE 0] previous: null, next: [null, null, null, null, null, null]
[FORMSTATE 1] change: 2, value: 9
[FORMSTATE 0] previous: [null, null, null, null, null, null], next: [null, null, 9, null, null, null]
```

My question is what causes this? How to change it to fulfill the expected case when a particular `TextField` in list of `TextField` at index `i` changes, the riverpod state at index `i` will also change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no listener for your notifier and therefore it is auto disposed.

You can verify it by adding a log statement with `ref.dispose` inside the notifier or setup a `ProviderObserver`.

https://docs-v2.riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/provider_observer

You could change the behaviour by adding `ref.watch(formStateProvider);` or `ref.listen(formStateProvider);` inside the widget's `build` method or set the notifier's `keepAlive` to true.

Answer (score -1):

Notice how you have two logs with state 0.
This probably means that you are rebuilding `FormState` every time you add a value.

You should check where the `build()` method gets called and make sure you are not accidentaly rebuilding the state.

Comment: Yeah, I have debugged it and it shows that it always rebuilding, why is it happening? and how to handle it so it won't rebuild every `change` method is called?

Comment: You should debug further to spot the point in your code where you initialize FormState. It's unclear from the code you posted in your question, cannot help you further